# Replace values in multiple columns, on condition from another variable, with R data.table

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, melt

A big*ish* data.table with 750k rows and almost 200 columns, but this will do:

```
dt <- data.table(id = 1:15,
             outcome = factor(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 1, 1, 3),
                              labels = c("F0","F1","F3")),
             var1 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
             var2 = c(0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4))
```

I want to change/group the "labels" of the variables var1, var2, (and any other variable) by a condition in the outcome variable. A table explains visually what I want to change

```
xtabs(~var1+outcome, dt, addNA = TRUE)
xtabs(~var2+outcome, dt, addNA = TRUE)
```

When outcome==F1 has no occurrences, the labels of var1, var2, and any other variables should be grouped. From the 1st table: change 2; from the 2nd table, group 0 and 6.

If the number of levels and variables were small, I *could* do this by hand with *one liners*:

```
dt$var1[dt$var1==2] <- "nF"                                  #data frame way
dt[, var1 := as.character(var1)][var1 == "2", var1 := "nF"]  #data.table way
xtabs(~var1+outcome, dt, addNA = TRUE)                       #check

      outcome
var1   F0 F1 F3
  0     4  2  2
  1     0  2  0
  nF    0  0  3
  <NA>  0  0  2
```

Both of these *one liners* work, but as you can imagine, with 200 columns and some variables with over a thousand levels, this is impossible.

So I came up with an idea:

1. build a table for every variable with respect to the outcome
2. get the labels where outcome==F1 has 0 occurrences
3. change the variable with an ifelse statement

Step 1

```
#rebuild dt to try this
(temp1 <- dcast(data = dt,
           formula = var2 ~ outcome,
           value.var = "outcome",
           fun.aggregate = length))
```

Step 2

```
tempvar <- temp1[F1==0 & var2!="NA", var2]
```

Step 3

```
dt[, var2 := ifelse(var2 %in% tempvar, "nF", var2)]
xtabs(~var2+outcome, dt, addNA = TRUE)                       #check


      outcome
var2   F0 F1 F3
  4     0  2  1
  nF    3  0  6
  <NA>  1  2  0
```

This also works, and I avoid having to go through all those labels. So I made it a for loop... with a very cool counter =p

```
# Initialize
tabs <- c()
temp <- c()
counter <- 0

for (i in colnames(dt[, c("var1", "var2")])) {

# counter & progress
counter <- counter + 1
cat("Variable: ", counter, "of", ncol(dt), " ", i, "\n")

# build tables for each variable with dcast
tabs[[i]] <- dcast(data = dt,
                 formula = dt[[i]] ~ outcome,
                 value.var = "outcome",
                 fun.aggregate = length)

# temp: labels to group & set name
temp[[i]] <- data.table(tabs[[i]][F1==0 & dt!="NA", dt],
                      "nF")
colnames(temp[[i]])[1] <- i
}

# Names of the 1st column for each tabs (for some reason, I couldn't do it inside the loop)
for(i in 1:length(tabs)) {colnames(tabs[[i]])[1] <- names(tabs[i])}
```

This works fine... so far. Now let us look at temps and tabs:

```
#temp has the labels to be changed for each variable
temp

#tabs has the tables for each variable with respect to the outcome
tabs
```

And this is it. I'm stuck, I've been at this for 2 days and almost all Stackoverflow links are purple. Now I don't know how to do the rest.

- Did I overdo it? - Is there a better way?
- Any help you can send my way? would prefer data.table due to speed, but at this point, I won't complain.

Thanks,
Aldo

Comment: Cool counter. However, could you paste what the expected output should look like?

Comment: @NelsonGon edited to show the expected outcome

Comment: Why don’t you melt first before you perform your operations?

Comment: @chinsoon12, yup! I was getting very close with melt after posting it. I guess a good night of sleep does wonders; but It still doesn't work 100%. Alexis answer works, but i'm still learning why it does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly,
this does what you want:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(id = 1:15,
                 outcome = factor(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 1, 1, 3),
                                  labels = c("F0","F1","F3")),
                 var1 = as.character(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)),
                 var2 = as.character(c(0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4)))

long <- melt(dt, "outcome", setdiff(names(dt), c("id", "outcome")))

to_group <- long[, .(dummy = .N), by = .(outcome, variable, value)
                 ][, .(value = setdiff(value, c(NA, value[outcome == "F1"]))), by = "variable"]

for (var in unique(to_group$variable)) {
  dt[list(to_group[variable == var, value]), (var) := "nF", on = var]
}

dt[]
    id outcome var1 var2
 1:  1      F0    0   nF
 2:  2      F0    0   nF
 3:  3      F0    0 <NA>
 4:  4      F1    1 <NA>
 5:  5      F1    1 <NA>
 6:  6      F3   nF   nF
 7:  7      F3   nF   nF
 8:  8      F3   nF   nF
 9:  9      F3 <NA>   nF
10: 10      F3 <NA>   nF
11: 11      F0    0   nF
12: 12      F3    0   nF
13: 13      F1    0    4
14: 14      F1    0    4
15: 15      F3    0    4
```

Changing to long format with `melt` makes it easier to apply the subsequent logic for each `var*` column.
For your demo data,
`long` looks like this:

```
> head(long)
   outcome variable value
1:      F0     var1     0
2:      F0     var1     0
3:      F0     var1     0
4:      F1     var1     1
5:      F1     var1     1
6:      F3     var1     2
```

Therefore, you can think of the `[, .(dummy = .N), by = .(outcome, variable, value)]` frame as a "distinct" operation.
It will create something similar to `xtabs` but without adding 0 to non-existing combinations.

The next frame simply takes the set of all values for each `var*` and removes those that appear at the same time as `outcome == "F1"`,
as well as `NA`.
This is like computing the 0 counts for values that never appear when `outcome` is `F1`.

The code in the for-loop uses [secondary indices notation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-secondary-indices-and-auto-indexing.html).
For each `var*` column,
it searches for rows where the values match what is present in `to_group$value`,
and replaces said values with `"nF"`.

I'm not sure if that's the most efficient,
but since you said you wanted to modify the original `dt`
(possibly to keep `id`),
this is what I came up with.
You might want to `rm(long)` in the end.

Comment: **this one works**. I see you changed to `as.character` before everything; `rm(long)` will be _necessary_ with my original dataset. After a good night sleep,I thought  I should try with melt. I'm very close with my method, but your answer works. Also, **secondary indices notation; TIL**